What is the function of "als" in this sentence being confused about it
Can you explain and expand the function and meaning of "als" in the way that used in this sentence? What is the aim of author by using it in that way? İ am trying to understand it accurately.

Was bei einer Erhebung solcher Art und dem durch sie eingeleiteten Läuterungsproceß im Innern des Menschen vorgeht, kann man sich faßlich machen an Dem, was jeder erregbare Mensch beim Zuschauen eines Trauerspiels erfährt, als womit es verwandter Natur ist.



(eines Trauerspiels) als womit es verwandter Natur ist

The sentence is a relative clause introduced by womit; als does not serve any function here and would not be accepted in present-day German. A cursory glance at Schopenhauer's writing yields other instances.

http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Schopenhauer,+Arthur/Die+Welt+als+Wille+und+Vorstellung/Erster+Band/Erstes+Buch
Wirkung und Ursache giebt es aber nur für den Verstand, als welcher nichts weiter, als das subjektive Korrelat derselben ist.
Dies Verfahren unterscheidet nun unsere Betrachtungsart ganz und gar von allen je versuchten Philosophien, als welche alle entweder vom Objekt oder vom Subjekt ausgiengen
dies hingegen ist der Fall mit dem Gesetze der Trägheit, als welches aus dem der Kausalität folgt

See also DWB, als, under II. 5. The article mentions that this type of als was commonly used by Goethe (whom Schopenhauer admired).

dem relativpronomen tritt als hervorhebend bei, wie lat. quippe dem qui: ich wil des menschen leben rächen an einem jeglichen menschen, als der sein bruder ist. 1 Mos. 9, 5
diese ruhige form ist Göthen behaglich: traute sich kaum aus dem zimmer heraus zu gehen, als in welchem sie allein ruhe hatte.


Yes, I was so confused by this years ago, because it leads you on a totally different path of parsing the sentence if you don't know about this. BTW, in the hessian/palatian dialect (hssisch/pälzisch), "als" is used as a strange particle with a lot of different meanings: https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=PfWB&lemid=A01434
